# Swift program to open a downloaded app on my iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, button

I'm working on an app right now, and I'm trying to create a button that opens an app that the user has downloaded. Thanks to previous questions, I got SOME working code (Swift).  I have the following.

```
@IBAction func Website(_ sender: Any) {

    let powerHooks = "mspbi://app/"

    let powerUrl = NSURL(string: powerHooks)
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(powerUrl! as URL)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(powerUrl! as URL)

    } else {
        //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Power BI
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "http://powerbi.microsoft.com")! as URL)
    }
}
```

Basically, I have a button that, when clicked, is supposed to open the Microsoft Power BI app I have on my iPad.  Unfortunately, I keep getting the error "This app is not allowed to query for scheme mspbi?  The URI I have is straight from Microsoft's website. Thoughts on how to open the app?  It always skips the "if" and goes right to "else"

Comment: I'd like to ask a follow up! So I am now correctly opening the Power BI app on my iPad with this button...which I'm really excited.  However, I'd love to take it one step further. I want to have the URI/URL to change based on where the user is navigating in the app.  For example, if the user is in page 1 of my app, I want the button to direct them to the login page of Power BI. If the user is in page 2 of my app, I want the button to direct them to a project page of Power BI.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the URL scheme to the app's `Info.plist`

From the [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl) for `canOpenURL(_:)`:

> **Important**
>
> If your app is linked on or after iOS 9.0, you must declare
>   the URL schemes you want to pass to this method. Do this by adding the
>   `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key to your app's `Info.plist` file. If you
>   call this method for a scheme not declared using that key, this method
>   always returns false, whether or not an appropriate app is installed.
>   To learn more about the key, see [LSApplicationQueriesSchemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/plist/info/LSApplicationQueriesSchemes).

So in `Info.plist` create a new `Array` with key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and add an item with value `mspbi`.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that this was only something I could do if I was trying to open my own app.  Is that false?

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Davis Yes you can do it for any 3rd-party app that defines their URL scheme

Comment: @Davis glad to hear it, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd appreciate it if you could mark this answer as accepted

Comment: @Davis you need to do add `CFBundleURLTypes` key with appropriate values if you want your own app to be opened from other apps, but you need `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` if you want to open 3rd party apps from your own app.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the following lines to your application's `Info.plist` file to be able to handle app URLs:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>mspbi</string> //not sure if this is the correct entry, you will have to check for the specific app
    <string>uber</string>  //as an example, this is the working entry for opening the Uber app from your app
</array>
```